# How to design a AudioPlayerUI in Modern AndroidTV app using PlaybackSupportFragment with MediaPlayerAdapter and PlaybackTransportControlGlue

Tags: android, android-tv, leanback

I am developing a Android TV music app. I want to develop following UI. However the sample Google provide is using deprecated classes. Their documentation states to use the following classes.

I cant understand how to use [MediaPlayerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/media/MediaPlayerAdapter) with [PlaybackTransportControlGlue](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/media/PlaybackTransportControlGlue) extending [PlaybackSupportFragment](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/leanback/app/PlaybackSupportFragment) to get the UI similar to [MusicConsumptionFragment](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/blob/master/LeanbackShowcase/app/src/main/java/androidx/leanback/leanbackshowcase/app/media/MusicConsumptionExampleFragment.java) where one has CoverPhoto, title, description and a list of rows for episodes with like and add to playlist action.

I want to develop [UI similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpw6v.png) and referring to samples [ClassicsKotlin](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/master/ClassicsKotlin) and [LeanbackShowcase](https://github.com/android/tv-samples/tree/master/LeanbackShowcase) (deprecated classes used in MusicConsumptionFragment to build Player UI). Classic Kotlin sample has a example to video and uses a UI for Video Playback but I want a Audio Player UI

I need help with understanding to build audio player UI, or change the Video sample UI into audio player UI.

[image: audio player reference ui]